# Calculating the limit of a sequence

Tags: limits

I'm currently studying limits because of my calculus class and i've wondered how for example wolfram alpha computes the limit of a sequence. Is it more a brute force way, or is there an efficient method to calculate/find them?

Comment: I would guess, since most of the sequences we give are monotonic it would search for a greatest lower bound or least upper bound(if at all the sequence is convergent).

Answer (score 2):

Different sequences require different methods. I'm sure alpha has a suite of methods available and it analyzes the sequence to see which (if any) of its methods applies. Not all that different from the way humans do it.

Comment: Additionally, the most expedient route for a machine may not be the easiest route for a human, and vice-versa.